# Should Secret Q&A be avoided?

Tags: security, authentication, passwords, password-recovery, owasp

Browsing over the OWASP site, one can find the article where at the very bottom secret Q&A is ditched not only as ineffective, but as security backdoor to the system:

[OWASP: Guide to Authentication](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Authentication#Secret_Questions_And_Answers)

> Questions and answers are back door credentials - they equate to the username and password for the user. Often such schemes use "Mother's Maiden Name" or other easily found information. If all systems use the same Q&As, it will be possible to break into many accounts using the same information.
>   They are unacceptable for the following reasons:
>   Collection of information about people without their explicit consent (such as "Mother's maiden name") is illegal in most privacy regimes. Such collection is subject to privacy laws, review and correction by the subject, and so on.
>   IT Security Policies and standards such as ISO 27000 prohibit the clear text storage of passwords, but almost all Q&A schemes store both the question and answer in the clear
>   The information in the answers is public for a goodly portion of the users of the Internet, and thus is found using public sources
>   Secret Questions and Answers have been publicly abused, most notably by the attack on Sarah Palin's e-mail account, exposing her use of her Yahoo free mail account for government business.

Then again, if you browse to:

[OWASP: Authentication Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet#Implement_Secure_Password_Recovery_Mechanism)

You can actually find a link to password reset implementation that includes Secret Q&A as part of the process.

This makes it bit inconsistent to make a good decision whether Secret Q&A is bad practice or not. What I've come up with is the following conclusion:

- If used as single method for password recovery, Secret Q&A is bad practice
- If used combined with token delivered through independent channel such as e-mail or SMS, Secret Q&A adds another layer of security

If i.e. system is using reset token only that is sent over e-mail, if attacker has gained access to user's e-mail, then all applications that are using that e-mail address can be accessed by the attacker initiating password reset procedure.

If however, using token requires you to perform Secret Q&A steps as well, then regardless the e-mail is infiltrated, attacker still can't access the web applications.

This being said, there is still no best practice on whether Secret Question must be collected from the user, or user can be asked to select question from the list of predefined questions (usability scenario).

Additionally, it is unclear whether Secret Answer should be hashed (some mechanisms are hashing it, some are not), and same applies for user-supplied Secret Question.

Is there some other standard that defines all this beyond OWASP?

Answer (score 1):

**Should Secret Q&A be Used?**

You already explained where secret questions should and should not be used, and why, quite well. They are almost always much weaker than a traditional username and password combination, but if used as secondary verification to another method, they can certainly add to the security of your password reset process.

**Implementation**

I would suggest using predefined questions over user defined ones. While a user can create a much stronger Q&A than you should probably force upon them, they can also set one like 
"Q: A sweet fruit that keeps the doctor away," which you really can't prevent, but provides no protection at all.

Should the answer be hashed? Probably.

But if you are going to hash it, I would suggest doing things like setting it to all lower case first; things like capitalization are important in a password, but the point of a secret Q&A is that the (correct) user can come into it cold and give the correct answer. Allowing things like capitalization to break that is probably a bad idea. In fact, I might go so far as to remove anything that is not alpha-numeric, so that a period, dash, etc don't break the match. Of course, anything you do that removes entropy further weakens the secret Q&A, just like it would on a password, so you have to make a judgement call on just how critical your security really is.

**Other Standards**

I don't know of any other standard that goes beyond OWASP.